# VS Code FTP Simple working as Atom FTP Edit

Tags: visual-studio-code, ftp, atom-editor

I have been using Atom for a long time, at the end it has been just for comfort but for the last few weeks I have been using VS Code, and I am delighted with the IDE, so I want to completely migrate to it.

But the only thing I'm missing from VS Code is the functionality that Atom Editor has with the ftp (`ftp-edit` extension) plugin that allows me to navigate through the ftp directory without previously downloading the files, just when I open files or directories in IDE perse. Instead the extension `ftp-simple` of VS Code doesn't allow me to use this functionality (or at least I haven't know how to find it) so I have to download the entire ftp tree, and on each connection I have to wait as long as it takes to get off.

Any idea about this configuration or if this is any parameter in some config file?

I know about the [other stacks](https://superuser.com) but I didn't recive any answer for this.

Cheers!

Comment: Though, it's offtop, it's important question I don't know the answer for.

Comment: Well, I don't know where to ask